# python regular expression match comma

Tags: python, regex

In the following string,how to match the words including the commas

1. --

   ```
   process_str = "Marry,had ,a,alittle,lamb"
   import re

   re.findall(r".*",process_str)
   ['Marry,had ,a,alittle,lamb', '']
   ```
2. --

   ```
   process_str="192.168.1.43,Marry,had ,a,alittle,lamb11"

   import re
   ip_addr = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}",l)          
   re.findall(ip_addr,process_str1)
   ```

   How to find the words after the ip address excluding the first comma only
   i.e, the outout again is expected to be `Marry,had ,a,alittle,lamb11`
3. In the second example above how to find if the string is ending with a digit.

Comment: I have made the edit please look at it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example, you just need to capture (using `()`) everything that follows the ip:

```
 import re

 s = "192.168.1.43,Marry,had ,a,alittle,lamb11"
 text = re.findall(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3},(.*)", s)[0]
 // text now holds the string Marry,had ,a,alittle,lamb11
```

To find out if the string ends with a digit, you can use the following:

```
re.match(".*\d$", process_str)
```

That is, you match the entire string (`.*`), and then backtrack to test if the last character (using `$`, which matches the end of the string) is a digit.

Comment: What about the third one..ending with a digit??

Answer (score 1):

Find the words including the commas, that's how I understand this sentence:

```
>>> re.findall("\w+,*", process_str)
['Marry,', 'had', 'a,', 'alittle,', 'lamb']
```

ending with a didgit:

```
"[0-9]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. The examples are not quite clear, but it seems in example #2, you want to only match text , commas, space-chars, and ignore digits? How about this:

```
re.findall('(?i)([a-z, ]+), process_str)
```

I didn't quite understand the "if the string is ending with a digit". Does that mean you ONLY want to match 'Mary...' IF it ends with a digit? Then that would look like this:

```
re.findall('(?i)([a-z, ]+)\d+, process_str)
```

Comment: It makes the regular expression case `i`nsensitive.